# Two modules with same method names included in same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I am working with ruby on rails and I am basically trying to include two modules into the same model/class with both modules having the same method names. An example will be demonstrated below, however my questions are:

Is there a way to include module conditionally? or 
Is there a way to invoke based on the specific instance of the class.

An example is a simple complete profile wizard.

**How its suppose to work**

Case 1: If the user is lets say a Transporter, step_one is completed when the user has a company_name is present.

Case 2: On the otherhand if the user is a Client, step_one is completed when the user has a telephone present.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include ClientWizard
  include TransporterWizard
end

module ClientWizard
 def step_one_completed?
  self.name.present?
 end
end

module TransporterWizard
 def step_one_completed?
  self.company_name.present?
 end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

No, module methods all exist within the class's namespace. Consequently, this doesn't seem like a particularly good use case for modules.

You could give the methods module-specific names (`client_wizard_step_one_completed?`), but I'd recommend instead defining the wizards as separate classes, and passing the user instance as a parameter.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def client_wizard
    ClientWizard.new(self)
  end
end

class ClientWizard
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def step_one_completed?
    @user.name.present?
  end
end
```

Comment: This look greaaat! Thank you very much. A couple of questions: I presume I can encapsulate(namespace if I’m using the term wrong) both classes. Also how can I share common methods. Thank you once again.

Comment: Yeah, you can define those classes wherever is convenient. You could share functionality through inheritance (maybe ClientWizard < UserWizard, and UserWizard < WizardBase), or by then using a module you include into each wizard that needs it.